# How to have `pkgdown` use figure numbers and cross-references in vignettes?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, vignette, pkgdown

I've created several vignettes for a package, with figures I want to reference in the text.
Using the template for a `.Rmd` vignette, I can do this by using `bookdown::html_document2` as follows in my yaml header:

```
output: 
  bookdown::html_document2:
    base_format: rmarkdown::html_vignette
    fig_caption: yes
    toc: true
```

Yet, when I build the associated `pkgdown` site, I don't get figure numbers or cross-references,
done with `\@ref(fig:chunk_name)`.

Is there some magic I can add to my `_pkgdown.yml` file to have it use the bookdown output format?

**Edit**: Not sure if this has anything to do with this issue, but my figure chunk labels are of the form `topic-figure` rather than `topic_figure`.
E.g.,

````
```{r, plastic1-HE3D}
#| echo=FALSE,
#| fig.cap="3D HE plot for the plastic MLM"
knitr::include_graphics("fig/plastic-HE3D.png")
```
````

Answer (score 2):

A solution that seems to work is suggested in https://github.com/r-lib/pkgdown/issues/2201

Essentially, add `pkgdown: as_is: true` to the yaml headers of vitnettes:

```
output: 
  bookdown::html_document2:
    base_format: rmarkdown::html_vignette
    fig_caption: yes
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 2
pkgdown:
  as_is: true
```